# How can I validate CakePHP 3 field input against XSS, while allowing versatile use for text input?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, xss

I am currently fixing up a CakePHP 3 application. I have run into some text fields that allow  tags to be inserted into the database, which would allow a user to to perform XSS attacks against other users in the system.

I have come up with the following rule to apply to fields having this issue in the effected table objects, to prevent html from being added into the database:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    ...

    $validator
        ->add('description', 'validFormat', [
            'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i'),
            'message' => 'Input must not contain special characters.'
        ]);

    ...
}
```

However this is a bit restrictive and does not allow punctuation and special characters to be used in plenty of real use cases for the software.

I would like to implement a rule that gives the user the most flexibility to write text into this description field, but prevents them from entering code that is capable of exploiting XSS vulnerabilities.

What would be the proper rule for doing this? It seems like this would be a common use case in Cake, is there a pre-existing rule in the framework to do this without regex too?

I understand that printing the output from these fields as plain text is another solution to handle this, and I intend to do that as well. Although I would like to have the data be properly formatted on the input side too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake by default relies on you sanitizing user input when it's displayed, rather than when it's captured. Their own baked templates show that they wrap user-input values with [h()](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#h), shorthand for `htmlspecialchars`, to prevent XSS:

```
<td><?= h($example->description) ?></td>
```

Sanitizing input against XSS is full of potential pitfalls and complications, it's far simpler to just sanitize on display. It can't really be done with a line of regex that *also* won't place undue burdens on your users (like you noted, with this they can use any punctuation whatsoever). Offering even a limited set of punctuation can still be dangerous.

Note that `h()` only protects you against basic HTML injection (so, good enough in the example above). You still need to consider additional protections when placing data script tags and other [certain circumstances](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).